# Get serial date numbers from datenum in MATLAB from an input cell array

Tags: matlab

From reading in this Excel file into MATLAB

```
[frates, fdlable] = xlsread('C:\Users\Nancy\Documents\Research\Data\USTreasury\USTreasuryDataset\FredTreasuryRatesMon','A8:X818')
```

I get a cell array rates `fdlable1` 811 by 12 of Excel dates, format `m/d/yyyy`  that I want convert to serial date numbers through `datenum`

Must I convert fdlable1  'm/d/yyyy' to a string variable first before using datenum?

**Here the assignment fails because there are empty cells in fdlable1:**

```
date_num = cellfun(@datenum, fdlable1, 'UniformOutput', false);
Warning: Usage of DATENUM with empty date character vectors or empty strings is not supported.
Results may change in future versions.
```

```
fdlable1 =fdlable(:,1:2:23);  811 x 12 from 811 x 23
```

**fdlable:**

```
'7/1/1954'  ''  '7/1/2001'  ''  '1/1/1934'  ''  '12/1/1958'
'8/1/1954'  ''  '8/1/2001'  ''  '2/1/1934'  ''  '1/1/1959'
'9/1/1954'  ''  '9/1/2001'  ''  '3/1/1934'  ''  '2/1/1959'
'10/1/1954' ''  '10/1/2001' ''  '4/1/1934'  ''  '3/1/1959'
'11/1/1954' ''  '11/1/2001' ''  '5/1/1934'  ''  '4/1/1959'
'12/1/1954' ''  '12/1/2001' ''  '6/1/1934'  ''  '5/1/1959'
'1/1/1955'  ''  '1/1/2002'  ''  '7/1/1934'  ''  '6/1/1959'
'2/1/1955'  ''  '2/1/2002'  ''  '8/1/1934'  ''  '7/1/1959'
'3/1/1955'  ''  '3/1/2002'  ''  '9/1/1934'  ''  '8/1/1959'
'4/1/1955'  ''  '4/1/2002'  ''  '10/1/1934' ''  '9/1/1959'
'5/1/1955'  ''  '5/1/2002'  ''  '11/1/1934' ''  '10/1/1959'
'6/1/1955'  ''  '6/1/2002'  ''  '12/1/1934' ''  '11/1/1959'
'7/1/1955'  ''  '7/1/2002'  ''  '1/1/1935'  ''  '12/1/1959'
'8/1/1955'  ''  '8/1/2002'  ''  '2/1/1935'  ''  '1/1/1960'
```

**fdlable1:**

```
'7/1/1954'  '7/1/2001'  '1/1/1934'  '12/1/1958' '7/1/1959'  '4/1/1953'
'8/1/1954'  '8/1/2001'  '2/1/1934'  '1/1/1959'  '8/1/1959'  '5/1/1953'
'9/1/1954'  '9/1/2001'  '3/1/1934'  '2/1/1959'  '9/1/1959'  '6/1/1953'
'10/1/1954' '10/1/2001' '4/1/1934'  '3/1/1959'  '10/1/1959' '7/1/1953'
'11/1/1954' '11/1/2001' '5/1/1934'  '4/1/1959'  '11/1/1959' '8/1/1953'
'12/1/1954' '12/1/2001' '6/1/1934'  '5/1/1959'  '12/1/1959' '9/1/1953'
'1/1/1955'  '1/1/2002'  '7/1/1934'  '6/1/1959'  '1/1/1960'  '10/1/1953'
'2/1/1955'  '2/1/2002'  '8/1/1934'  '7/1/1959'  '2/1/1960'  '11/1/1953'
'3/1/1955'  '3/1/2002'  '9/1/1934'  '8/1/1959'  '3/1/1960'  '12/1/1953'
'4/1/1955'  '4/1/2002'  '10/1/1934' '9/1/1959'  '4/1/1960'  '1/1/1954'
```

How to get a matrix of serial date numbers?

The corresponding variable rates is:

```
**rates = frates(:,1:2:23); 811 x 12**

0.800000000000000   3.61000000000000    0.720000000000000   3.01000000000000
1.22000000000000    3.48000000000000    0.620000000000000   3.09000000000000
1.07000000000000    2.63000000000000    0.240000000000000   3.13000000000000
0.850000000000000   2.24000000000000    0.150000000000000   3.13000000000000
0.830000000000000   1.96000000000000    0.160000000000000   3.27000000000000
1.28000000000000    1.69000000000000    0.150000000000000   3.33000000000000
1.39000000000000    1.65000000000000    0.150000000000000   3.52000000000000
1.29000000000000    1.70000000000000    0.190000000000000   3.82000000000000
1.35000000000000    1.75000000000000    0.210000000000000   3.87000000000000
1.43000000000000    1.69000000000000    0.270000000000000   4.70000000000000
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a sample of `fdlable` and `frates` along with exact expected results. Please see how to create a [mre] and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The MATLAB function [`cellfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) allows you to "_Apply function to each cell in cell array_". You can use that in conjunction with `datenum`.

Comment: I edited my question. Should I resubmit or will it automatically repost after editing?   Thank you

Comment: `fdlable` indeed has some empty cells, but `fdlable1` seems ok. Are you sure you used `fdlable1` in your call to `cellfun` ?